# Entity Framework find fails unless you call toList first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, mysql-connector

Using Entity framework 6 and Mysql connector and guids for ids (in case any of that matters).

I'm new to EF and I'm hoping I'm just doing something stupid but I cannot find anything that tells me so.

If I try to find by id like below job will be null.

```
var job = _Context.JobRepository.Find(id);
```

But if I simply get a list first then select the job

```
var tempList = _Context.JobRepository.ToList();
var job = _Context.JobRepository.Find(id);
```

it will load it correctly. I am guessing because it is cached from the toList? But either way it should be able to load straight from the database correct? If not how does one select a single object by id from the database?

Also other forms of selecting one object by id don't even work if I load the list first

for example these

```
var job = _Context.JobRepository.FirstOrDefault( h => h.Id == id );
var job = _Context.JobRepository.SingleOrDefault( h => h.Id == id );
var job = _Context.JobRepository.Where( h => h.Id == id ).FirstOrDefault();
var job = (from h in _Context.JobRepository where h.Id == id select h).FirstOrDefault();
```

I currently have proxies and lazyloading turned off but I have tried it with them both turned on. If you need more information please ask (though I feel like it shouldn't have to do with the structure of the database/entity seeing as it can be loaded if using toList first )

Edit: adding model

```
[DataContract, Table( "ada_job" )]
public class Job
{
//Members
//left out because they don't get mapped only properties do

public Job()
{       
    CheckConfigInterval = 15 * 60 * 1000;
}

//Properties
[NotMapped]
public JobId JobID { get; set;  }
[Key, Column( "job_id" )] //Only used for saving / loading (I like strongly typed ids)
public virtual Guid Id { get { return ID; } set { ID = new JobId(value); } }

[DataMember, Column( "job_name" )]
public virtual String JobName { get; set; }

[DataMember, Column( "check_settings_interval" )]
public virtual int CheckConfigInterval { get; set; }

[Column( "last_checked_settings" )]
public virtual DateTime LastCheckedConfig { get; set; }

[Column( "date_modified" )]
public virtual DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

// left out unmapped properties
// left out functions
}
```

There is actually more to the class but I did just now tested it with only what you see here and the results are the same. I removed all other DBSets from the context so nothing was marring my test.

Comment: Could you show please your models?

Comment: @Inanikian Added the model in question. Sorry for taking so long to reply I thought stack overflow didn't actually post the question for a day. Also for my test I reduced the context to just using that single model so even though I left stuff out it shouldn't matter. The datacontract/Datamember annotations are for WCF and should be unrelated

Comment: So I changed my id to a byte array instead of a guid and it not can find it fine. So I'm assuming it has something to do with mysql connector